# What is the average of two stochastic processes multiplied?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes, dirac-delta

Consider two random processes $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ for which
$$\langle X(t) X(t') \rangle = \mu_X^2 + \sigma_X^2 \delta(t-t')$$
$$\langle Y(t) Y(t') \rangle = \mu_Y^2 + \sigma_Y^2 \delta(t-t')$$
ie. the processes are delta-correlated in time but have a non-zero mean. $X$ and $Y$ are independent processes.

My questions is: what is
$$\langle X(t) X(t') Y(t) Y(t') \rangle$$
?

Since they are independent, I should be able to do
$$\langle X(t) X(t') Y(t) Y(t') \rangle = \langle X(t) X(t')\rangle \langle Y(t) Y(t') \rangle \\
= \mu_X^2\mu_Y^2 + \mu_X^2\ \sigma_Y^2\delta(t-t) + \mu_Y^2\ \sigma_X^2\delta(t-t)  + \sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y^2 (\delta(t-t))^2 $$
but I don't know how to make sense of the squared delta function... How do I use that in an integral such as
$$\int_0^T \int_0^T (\cdot) \, dt dt'$$
?

Thank you in advance. Any help will be much appreciated.

If it makes a difference you can assume both processes Gaussian.

Comment: I fixed the sign in the first two equations.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to consider the correlations as being piecewise defined: 
$$ \langle X(t) X(t') \rangle = \mu_X^2 ~~ \textrm{if} ~~ t \neq t', \\
 \langle X(t) X(t') \rangle = \mu_X^2 + \sigma_X^2 ~~ \textrm{if} ~~ t = t',$$
and similarly for $Y$.  In this way you can calculate 
$$ \langle X(t) X(t')\rangle \langle Y(t)Y(t') \rangle = \mu_X^2 \mu_Y^2 ~~ \textrm{if} ~~ t \neq t', ~~\textrm{but} \\
 \langle X(t) X(t') \rangle\langle Y(t)Y(t') \rangle = (\mu_X^2 + \sigma_X^2)(\mu_Y^2 + \sigma_Y^2) ~~ \textrm{if} ~~ t = t'.$$
If you then reintroduce your delta function to distinguish the two you find that you have the same solution as you suggested, just with the $\delta^2$ replaced by a $\delta$.

For this reason, *in this context*, you can assert $\delta^2 = \delta$.